# Removing old .net installs before updating 

Tags: .net-framework, windows

I am planning install .net 4 on my xp machine. I found I have the following .net version on my machine:

```
.net Compact Framework2.0 SP2, 
.net Compact Framework3.5
.net Framework 2.0 Service Pack 2
.net Framework 3.0 Service Pack 2
.net Framework 3.5 SP1
```

Can I uninstall above old versions and just install the version 4?

My machine behave strangely in the past two weeks (outlook hang, die frequently and JVM cannot claim the amount of memory as before) and the .net update from Windows Update site couldn't go through. It just hang there forever.

I found there is an Framework 2.0 update being suspended there when I try to install an usb driver. I have to undo changes made by that suspended update. Then my C# application reports error to me. I think my machine is waiting for me to rebuild it again.

Answer (score 2):

No. .NET 4.0 is a different runtime environment from the others. You need each version that your applications depend on.